# Weird email spam issue. Google Domain Exchange email server

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, spam, cloud

We have a client who is blocking our email domain.

Their IT wrote this to us. I've never seen this be an issue before.

You are hosted on Google but have entries referring to Microsoft email protection (he's referring to our SPIF and DMARC). This will cause you to get flagged by every email server.

This makes no sense. We host our domain on Google but use exchange 365 for our emails so of course we have a SPIF and DMARC set for microsoft.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance, I appreciate it.

Comment: Without knowing the domain question it's hard to guess, but have you checked that other sources are seeing your SPF as correct and valid, for instance using https://mxtoolbox.com/spf.aspx to test it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean your client's IT team told you that your email was considered spam?
It seems there may be a misunderstanding. SPF and DMARC are email authentication methods. If you use Google to host your domain but use Microsoft Exchange 365 to host your email, it's completely normal to set up SPF and DMARC records for Microsoft. This is because your email is actually sent through Microsoft's servers, so you want the email server receiving the message to know that Microsoft is an authorized sender for your domain.

However, if the SPF and DMARC records are not set up correctly, problems may arise, such as your DMARC record not being configured correctly to include all necessary domain names and IP addresses or the SPF record not being properly configured to include all necessary servers and domains.

Therefore, it is recommended that you check your DMARC and SPF records to ensure they are configured correctly, for example using [MXToolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/) and online DMARC checking tools.

Comment: And that's the interesting thing. I ran the domain through MXToolbox, and everything checks out. The clients IT group doesn't make sense and I'm trying to get on the phone with them to figure things out. 

I'm not sure if the fact that the domain shows up as smartbuildingsacademy-com.mail.protection.outlook.com in MXtoolbox instead of just smartbuildingsacademy.com is an issue. I'm pretty familiar with networks but when you get into SPF/DMARC I'm out of my wheelhouse.